# Drawing conclusions on inequalities of integrals of probabilities.

Tags: inequality, probability-distributions

Suppose that I have three probability density functions $f(t)$, $g(t)$ and $h(t)$ (cumulative density distributions are $F(t)$, $G(t)$ and $H(t)$)  respectively, for which the following inequalities are valid:

$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(t)\cdot G(t)dt \geq \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} g(t)\cdot F(t)dt$

$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} g(t)\cdot H(t)dt \geq \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} h(t)\cdot G(t)dt$

$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(t)\cdot F(t)dt = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} g(t)\cdot G(t)dt = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} h(t)\cdot H(t)dt = 1/2$

$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(t)\cdot G(t)dt \geq \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} g(t)\cdot G(t)dt \geq \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} h(t)\cdot G(t)dt$

$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} g(t)\cdot H(t)dt \geq \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} g(t)\cdot G(t)dt \geq \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} g(t)\cdot F(t)dt$

Is it possible to conclude that $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(t)\cdot H(t)dt \geq \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} h(t)\cdot F(t)dt $? My reasoning is that on average $f(t)$ and $H(t)$ contribute more to the integrals than $h(t)$ and $F(t)$, however I do not have the mathematical instruments to make such claims. I would be much grateful if you could help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the corresponding random variables $X$, $Y$, and $Z$ with cdfs $F$, $G$, and $H$ respectively.  Your first inequality says $P(X\ge Y)\ge P(X\le Y)$, the second that $P(Y\ge Z) \ge P(Z\ge Y)$, the third is vacuuous, the fourth that $P(X\ge Y)\ge P(Z\ge Y)$ and the last that $P(Y\ge Z)\ge P(Y\ge X)$.  That is, $X$ beats $Y$ more often than not, $Y$ beats $Z$ more often than not, and you want to know if that implies $X$ beats $Z$ more often than not.  (All three random variables are continuous, so $\ge$ is the same as $>$ in each of the probability expressions, so $P(X>Y) \ge P(X<Y)$ and so on.)

The answer is *no*, and is famous enough to have a Wikipedia article, [Condorcet paradox,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Condorcet_paradox) about it. If each of the 3 rankings $X>Y>Z$, $Y>Z>X$, and $Z>X>Y$ are equally likely, the events $X>Y$ and $Y>Z$, although individually more likely than not to happen, are not independent and their joint occurrence is relatively rare.

Comment: I am thankful for your answer. It is indeed not intuitive. Do you know if is there any assumption that can be made to solve the paradox and allow the trasitivity to take place?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't know.